# Meaning of cross terms in multivariable Taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

The cross terms in the Taylor expansion of $f = f(x,y)$ in $(x_0,y_0)$ 
$$
f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + \ldots + \frac{1}{2!}\bigg( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (\Delta x)^2 + \color{green}{2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \Delta x \Delta y} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(\Delta y)^2 \bigg) + \ldots \tag{1}
$$ can be seen as to have arosen from the cross terms of 
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \bigg[ \bigg( \Delta x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \Delta y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg)^n \ f(x,y)\bigg]_{x_0,y_0} , \tag{2}
$$ 
where we consider the partial derivatives to only operate on $f$.

I'm missing the interpretation of these cross terms.

$(2)$ somewhat explains where the (algebraic structure of) these cross terms comes from, but it doesn't give me any insight as to why we need to consider the product of two changes. Moreover, I also don't grasp how my text arrives at $(2)$. Why are the cross terms included?

I understand the *operation* of mixed derivatives in terms of calculations, but I want to know how I can interpret them.

Furthermore, I also understand the concept of stationary points of multi-variable functions. I don't think the concept of stationary points are relevant here.

I'm not necessarily looking for a geometric interpretation; as long as the relevance of the mixed partial derivative terms is made evident.

Comment: Basically, the cross derivative term tells you how much the slope in one direction changes when you move along the other direction. Look forward and see how steep the graph is in that direction, then take a step to the right and compare. The fact that this is the same as looking to the right and taking a step forward is an important, but not obvious, result.

Comment: @Arthur That only explains what $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ is. I don't understand how the product $\Delta x \Delta y$ comes into the picture.

Comment: @Arthur I think we need to consider $\Delta x$ in concert with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Similarly for $\Delta y$. That is, instead of considering the product $\Delta x \Delta y$ as an object in itself.

Comment: For the cynical calculus reason, you want the Taylor expansion to have all the same second derivatives as the original function at $(x_0,y_0)$. Well, both $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\Delta x^2$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}\Delta y^2$ has zero cross derivative, so you need a term in there that has 1) non-zero cross derivative, and 2) zero all other derivatives. $\Delta x\Delta y$ is the only way to get that job done. The coefficient of that term is the cross derivative of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$. I can't think of an elegant geometric reason right now.

Comment: @Arthur *you want the Taylor expansion to have all the same second derivatives as the original function at $(x_0,y_0)$.*
Right! If we differentiate the left-hand side with respect to $\Delta x \Delta y$, it needs to agree with the left-hand side, indeed. 
But this doesn't shed any light on the meaning of the term (with the product $\Delta x \Delta y$) in itself. It only verifies that the relation (1) is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good way to visualize these sorts of formulas is to probe them with smooth curves so that you can invoke your 1-dimensional intuition.

Starting at $(x_0, y_0)$, suppose we move along the velocity vector $(v, w)$.  How do the values of $f$ change?  To answer this question we can look at the values of $f$ along the parametric curve $r(t) = (x_0 + vt, y_0 + wt)$.  By the chain rule we get:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(r(t)) = f_x(r(t)) v + f_y(r(t))w$$

and:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(r(t)) = \left(f_{xx}(r(t)) v^2 + f_{xy}(r(t)) vw \right) + \left(f_{yx}(r(t)) wv + f_{yy}(r(t)) w^2 \right)$$
$$= f_{xx}(r(t))v^2 + 2f_{xy}(r(t))vw + f_{yy}(r(t))w^2$$

Hopefully this explains the cross terms: they represent the fact that rate of change of $f$ in the $x$ direction - represented by $f_x$ - is itself changing in both the $x$ and $y$ directions, and similarly for $f_y$.  The quadratic behavior in $v$ and $w$ just says that faster motion away from $(x_0, y_0)$ (corresponding to larger displacements $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$) causes more dramatic changes in the values of $f$.

---

A separate remark: if you really don't like the cross terms then you can always get rid of them by changing coordinates (assuming $f$ is sufficiently regular).  To see this, write:

$$f_{xx} \Delta x^2 + 2f_{xy} \Delta x \Delta y + f_{yy} \Delta y^2 = (\Delta x, \Delta y) \left(\begin{array}{cc} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{xy} & f_{yy} \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} \Delta x \\ \Delta y \end{array}\right)\ \ \ $$

The $2 \times 2$ matrix in the middle - called the *Hessian* matrix of $f$ - is symmetric and hence it can be diagonalized by an orthonormal coordinate system $(u, v)$.  In this coordinate system the second derivative takes the form $f_{uu} \Delta u^2 + f_{vv} \Delta v^2$ - informally, this means that the rate of change in the $u$ direction does not itself change in the $v$ direction, and vice-versa.